# Str in Python's map and sum

Tags: python, string

**Why do you need to use the function 'str' in the following code?**

I am trying to count the sum of digits in a number.

**My code**

```
for i in number:
    sum(map(int, str(i))
```

where *number* is the following array

```
[7,79,9]
```

I read my code as follows

1. loop though the array such that
2. count sum of the integer digits
3. by getting given digits in a number by **map** increasingly
4. such that each object (given number) is converted to String   **// This does not make sense**

Manual says this for *str*

```
Type:           type
Base Class:     <type 'type'>
String Form:    <type 'str'>
Namespace:      Python builtin
Docstring:
    str(object) -> string

    Return a nice string representation of the object.
    If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
```

Comment: What you need to understand for this code is that strings are sequences of characters, and also what map() does.

Comment: Oh, and that int('5') will return the integer 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given `79` you need to get `[7, 9]` in order to sum up this list.

What does it mean to split a number into digits? It means to represent the number in a numerical system with some base (base `10` in this case). E. g. `79` is `7 * 10**1 + 9 * 10**0`.

And what is the simplest (well, at least in this context) way to get such a representation of a number? To convert it to a string of decimals!

Your code does exactly that:

```
>>> str(79)
'79'

# Another way to say this is [int(c) for c in str(79)]
>>> map(int, str(79))
[7, 9]

>>> sum(map(int, str(79)))
16
```

Comment: I found out that "strings" are immutable sequences of characters in Python such that you need first a new string to have your edits. - However, it does not make sense to me why you need to use `str`for 79 when it is a new input in your example. - **I wonder when you do not need to use the function `str` in the given example.**

Comment: **Do you mean that conversion to a decimal number allows to count the sum?** - It makes sense to me, since integers are unique, while decimals are non-unique. This would allow easily to have many pointers for different decimal presentations which is not possible for integers.

Comment: Numbers are just numbers. You can add or subtract them. But there is no such thing as digit as far as you do not define digit as a coefficient in a representation of a number in some numeric system.

You can write a function `num_to_digits`, that accepts an `int` and the numeric system base, and returns a `list` of `int`s. But you can just reuse `str` that does internally a) this thing, b) conversion from `int` digit to `str`.

Comment: Question: "I wonder when you do not need to use the function `str in the given example"
Aswer: When i is a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you try that code without using `str()`?

The `str()` is used to convert the integer into a sequence of characters, so that `map()` can iterate over the sequence. The key point here is that a "string" can be treated as a "sequence of characters".

Comment: **How can you see that `map()` needs charaters as an input?** - It says in the manual that *map(function, sequence[, sequence, ...]) -> list*. - **What is the data type for sequence?** - It seems to be possible that a sequence may consists letters only, not numbers.

Comment: In more well-typed languages `map` has the type: `forall a. (a -> b), list(a) -> list(b)`. Sequence (in fact `Iterable` here) in Python is something that has the `__iter__` method returning another thing called `Iterator`. Iterators have the same `__iter__` and `next` that does the actual iteration.

Comment: "It seems to be possible that a sequence may consists letters only, not numbers." No. Sequences of numbers are perfectly possible, like (1,2,3,4,5) for example.

Comment: And, it's necessary to keep in mind the difference between numbers (integers, like the mathematical concept), and characters (which may be a letter or a digit or punctuation or other character).

Answer (score 2):

**Why do you need to use the function 'str' in the following code?**

Because map takes an iterable, like a list or a tuple or a string.

The code in question adds upp all the numbers in an integer. And it does it by a little clever hack. It converts the number into a sequence of numbers by doing

```
map(int, str(i))
```

This will convert the integer 2009 to the list [2, 0, 0, 9]. The sum() then adds all this integers up, and you get 11.

A less hacky version would be:

```
>>> number = [7,79,9]
>>> for i in number:
...     result = 0
...     while i:
...         i, n = divmod(i, 10)
...         result +=n
...     print result
... 
7
16
9
```

But your version is admittedly more clever.

Comment: Yes, but yuo should basically abstract such a code as, for example, function `digits(number, base) -> [int]` and `sum`.

Comment: If you intend to use it more than once, yes.

Comment: Your code seems to be buggy. It seems to need `i = 0; while i < something` to the beginning. However, I could not get it work with these changes.

Comment: It only needs i to be some sort of integer, as it is in your question. That's it. No bugs. I double checked again.

Comment: @Lennart: I get `unsupported operand type(s) for divmod(): 'list' and 'int'` after running the code with the initial data in running the code with Ubuntu and with OS X Leopard. - **What is your output?**

Comment: Sigh. I used the exact same variable names as you did. I updated my post for extreme clarity.