# Python Flask app- leading zeros in TOTP error. (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, octal, one-time-password

I have written a python flask application in which app generate totp for validation. (Python 2.7)

I use onetimepass library to validate totp against the application secret. 
code:

```
    json_data=request.get_json()
    my_token=json_data['OTP']
    is_valid = otp.valid_totp(token=my_token, secret=my_secret)
```

However the issue i am facing is whenever a totp comes with leading zeroes it turns into an Octal number. 
OTP is always treated as incorrect and user is unable to login.

How can i preserve these leading zeroes in such case? any code snippets or guidance will be of much help.

Comment: isn't the token always a number? (whilst the magic is not)

Comment: Its always a number but leading zeroes make it into a octal number. See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1548437/4651101

Comment: I know, it's common.  What I wanted to say is, that you should not have non-decimal numbers here. Feed in decimal once, there is no leading 0 and it shall work (at least it does for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was simple as my_token was coming as string and i was converting it to a number. Adding this before converting to a number did the trick:

`my_token.lstrip("0") #removes leading characters`